# seleniumjs wait utill element is ready for input

Tags: javascript, selenium

my app is currently waiting for an iframe using `isElementPresent` then switching to it.

I am now having trouble on the iFrame itself, I need to wait until an `input` component is visible on the page and ready to accept keys however if the page loads slow its crashing the app (if the page loads fast it executes the key input on the iFrame component)

error message: `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`

```
Login.prototype.waitForIframeField = function(){
  var self = this;
  return this.driver.wait(function waitForInputField() {
    return self.driver.isElementPresent(self.page.usernameInputField.selector);
  }, this.config.driver.defaultTimeout);
}
```

I have also tried to use `.findElement().isDisplayed()` however it is also performing the same issue with `no such element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific [`elementIsVisible` built-in expected condition](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_until.html#elementIsVisible):

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(self.page.usernameInputField.selector)));
```

Note that you might also improve your iframe wait by switching to [`ableToSwitchToFrame`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/namespace_webdriver_until.html#ableToSwitchToFrame).

Comment: unfortunately when trying to use this I am getting  element.isDisplayed is not a function I am using a selector of {
      "xpath": "//*[@id=\"username\"]"
    } do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: @user2950720 I've made an update - does it work this way? Thanks.